# How to factorize $2x^2+5x+3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I'm doing pre-calculus course at coursera.org and I'm in trouble with this solution $$2x^2 +5x +3 = (2x+3)(x+1)$$

By trial, using ac-method I got stuck:
$$
ac = (2)(3) = 6\\
6 + ? = 5 \Rightarrow~ ? = 5 - 6 = -1
$$

Then,
$$2x^2+6x-x+3 = 2x(x+3)-x+3$$

At this point I could not get the answer, any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **product** of $2,\, 3$ is $6$, as you note.  The factors of $6$ which **sum** to $5$ are $\,2,\, 3.\;$  So we can write $$\begin{align} 2x^2 + 5x + 3 & = \color{blue}{2x^2 +} \underbrace{\color{blue}{2x} + \color{red}{3x}}_{= 5x} \color{red}{+ 3} \\ \\ &= \color{blue}{2x{\bf( x + 1)} } + \color{red}{3{\bf(x+1)}} \\ \\ & = {\bf(x+1)}(2x + 3)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 7):

**Hint** $\  $ Reduce to factoring a polynomial that is $\,\rm\color{#c00}{monic}\,$ (lead coeff $=1)$ as follows:

$$\quad\ \ \begin{eqnarray}
f &\,=\,& \ \  2\ x^2+\ 5\ x\ +\,\ 3\\
\Rightarrow\ 2f &\,=\,& (2x)^2\! + 5(2x)+6\\
         &\,=\,& \ \ \ \  \color{#c00}{X^2\!+ 5\  X\ +\,\ 6},\,\ \ X\, =\, 2x\\
         &\,=\,&  \ \ \,(X+2)\ (X+\,3)\\
         &\,=\,& \,\ (2x+2)\,(2x+3)\\
\Rightarrow\  f\,=\, 2^{-1}(2f)  &\,=\,&   \ \ \ \, (x+1)\,(2x+3)\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

If we denote our factoring algorithm by $\:\!\cal F\:\!$ then the above transformation is simply

$$\cal F f\,  = a^{-1}\cal F\, a\,f\quad\,$$

Thus we've transformed by $ $ *conjugation* $\,\ \cal F = a^{-1} \cal F\, a\ \,$ the problem of factoring non-monic polynomials into the simpler problem of factoring monic polynomials.
This is sometimes called the **AC method**. It works for higher degree polynomials too. As above, we can reduce the problem of factoring a non-monic polynomial to that of factoring a monic polynomial by scaling by a  $ $ *power* of the lead coefficient $\rm\:a\:$ then changing variables: $\rm\ X = a\,x\ $ (cf. $\rm\color{#0a0}{ac}\,$ below for name = $\rm\color{#0a0}{ac}$-method)

$$\begin{eqnarray} \rm\: a\:f(x)\:\! \,=\,\:\! a\:(a\:x^2 + b\:x + c)  &\,=\,&\rm\: X^2 + b\:X + \color{#0a0}{ac} =\, g(X),\ \ \ X = a\:x \\
\\
\rm\: a^{n-1}(a\:x^n\! + b\:x^{n-1}\!+\cdots+d\:x + c) &\,=\,&\rm\: X^n\! + b\:X^{n-1}\!+\cdots+a^{n-2}d\:X + a^{n-1}c
\end{eqnarray}$$
After factoring the monic $\rm\,g(X)\, =\, a^{n-1}f(x),\,$ we are guaranteed that the transformation reverses to yield a factorization of $\rm\:f,\ $ since $\rm\ a^{n-1}$ must divide into the factors of $\rm\ g\ $ by Gauss' Lemma, i.e. primes  $\,p\in\rm\mathbb Z\,$ remain prime in $\rm\,\mathbb Z[X],\,$ so $\rm\ p\ |\ g_1(x)\:g_2(x)\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\,\rm\:p\:|\:g_1(x)\:$ or $\rm\:p\:|\:g_2(x).$

This method also works for multivariate polynomial factorization, e.g. it applies to  [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/137424)

**Remark** $\ $ Those who know university algebra might be interested to know that this works not only for UFDs and GCD domains but also for integrally-closed domains satisfying

$\qquad\qquad$ [Primal Divisor Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/63330/242)  $\rm\ \ c\ |\ AB\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ c = ab,\ \ a\ |\: A,\ \ b\ |\ B$

Elements $c$ satisfying this are called *primal.* One easily checks that atoms are primal $\!\iff\!$ prime. Also products of primes are also primal. So "primal" may be viewed as a generalization of the notion "prime" from atoms (irreducibles) to composites.

Integrally closed domains whose elements are all primal are called $ $ *Schreier rings* by Paul Cohn (or *Riesz domains*, because they satisfy a divisibility form of the Riesz interpolation property). In Cohn's [Bezout rings and their subrings](http://www.lohar.com/researchpdf/bezout_rings_and_their_subrings.pdf)
he proved that if $\rm\:D\:$ is Shcreier then so too is $\rm\,D[x],\:$ by using a primal analogue of Nagata's Lemma: an atomic domain $\rm\:D\:$ is a UFD if some localization $\rm\:D_S\:$ is a UFD, for some monoid $\rm\:S\:$ generated by primes. These primal and Riesz interpolation viewpoints come to the fore in a *refinement view* of unique factorization, which proves especially fruitful in  noncommutative rings (e.g. see Cohn's 1973 *Monthly* survey [Unique factorization domains](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2319253)).

In fact Schreier domains can be characterized equivalently by a suitably formulated version of the above "factoring by conjugation" property. This connection between this elementary AC method and Schreier domains appears to have gone unnoticed in the literature.

Comment: I'm sorry, I could not understand how you do that $f=2x^2+5x+3 \iff 2f=(2x)^2+5(2x)+6$; shouldn't it be $(2)(2x)^2$? @bill-dubuque

Comment: @Lourenco $\ 2f\,$ has lead coeff $= 2(2x^2) = 4x^2 = (2x)^2.\ \ $ More generally $\ a^{n-1}(a x^n + g) = (ax)^n +\,\ldots\ $

Comment: Very informative and algebric answer. If it'd be possible, I'd maked it as an accepted answer together with the `amWhy' answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Lourenco  It matters much more to me that to know that you read the answer and found it helpful. Thanks very much for the feedback.

Answer (score 6):

$2x^2+5x+3=2x^2+3x+2x+3=x(2x+3)+(2x+3)=(2x+3)(x+1)$

Comment: any hint towards how you decide this approach? (eagle's eyes? :)

Comment: i have just saw it.

Answer (score 3):

In general, 
$$acx^2+(ad+bc)x+bd=(ax+b)(cx+d).$$
So, in your case, you need to find a set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ such that
$$ac=2, ad+bc=5, bd=3.$$

You have $2\times 4=8$ possibilities as
$$(a,c)=(1,2),(2,1)$$
$$(b,d)=(1,3),(3,1),(-1,-3),(-3,-1).$$
Now you can find a set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ such that $ad+bc=5.$

So, you'll find that $(a,b,c,d)=(1,1,2,3)$ is what you want. This means you can get
$$2x^2+5x+3=(x+1)(2x+3).$$

**P.S.** : You can use this method for this kind of factorization without any special technique.

Answer (score 2):

Complete squares:

$$2x^2+5x+3 = 2(x^2+2\alpha x + \alpha ^2) + (3- 2 \alpha ^2)$$

where $\alpha = \frac{5}{4}$. Then
$$(x+\frac{5}{4})^ 2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{25}{8}-3\right) $$
$$x+\frac{5}{4} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{16}} $$
$$x= \frac{-5}{4} \pm \frac{1}{4} = \frac{-5 \pm 1}{4}$$
$$ x\in \left\{-1, \frac{-3}{2}\right\}$$
Therefore,
$$2x^2+5x+3 = (x+1)(2x+3).$$

Answer (score 0):

In general
$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$where $x_1,x_2$ are the roots of equation
$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$
in case $a=2,b=5,c=3$ and roots are
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{-5\pm\sqrt{5^2-4\cdot2\cdot3}}{2\cdot2}=\frac{-5\pm1}{4},x_1=-1,x_2=-\frac{3}{2}$$ and put these above we get
$$2x^2+5x+3=2(x-(-1))(x-(-\frac{3}{2}))=$$
$$=2(x+1)(x+\frac{3}{2})=(x+1)(2x+2\cdot\frac{3}{2})=(x+1)(2x+3)$$