# remainder is not zero using long division method

Tags: polynomials, factoring

> Find all zeros of $f(x)=128x^3-48x^2+1$ given that one linear factor
>   occurs twice.

let $f(x) $ be equaal to 0

$128x^3-48x^2+1=0,$

$16x^2(8x-3)+1=0,$

trying $x=1/4$

$16/16(2-3)+1=0,$

$1(-1)+1=0=>0=0$

therefore, th zero of$f(x) $is 1/4 and factor is $4x-1$ and the remainder is 0

but after long division method i found that  the remainder is not coming to zero it is coming to 5.

please help me how to find all the factors.
thanks

Comment: I'd advise you to check the arithmetic in your long division.

Comment: okey....i try again

Comment: $\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\text{ it is easier to work with }\ 4f(x)\!\! &&= (8x)^3-3(8x)^2 +\, 4\\
&&=\ \ X^3 -\ 3\ \ X^2 \ +\ \ 4,\ \ \ X = 8x\\
\end{eqnarray}$  $\tag*{}$

The same idea works generally, see the [AC method.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/816069/242)

Answer (score 1):

A repeated root turns out to be a root of both $f(x) = 0$ and $f'(x) = 0$. That is, it must be a root of:

$$384x^2 - 96x = 0$$
$$4x^2 - x = 0$$
$$x(4x - 1) = 0$$
$$x = 0, \frac{1}{4}$$

Since $f\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) = 0$ and $f'\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) = 0$, it follows that $(4x - 1)$ is a double root of $f(x) = 0$. So we let

$$f(x) = (4x - 1)^2(ax + b)$$

for some real constants $a, b$.

To find $b$, we let $x = 0$. Then,

$$f(0) = b$$

But from the definition of $f(x)$, we have $f(0) = 1$. Hence $b = 1$.

Now to find $a$, we let $x = 1$. Then we have

$$f(1) = 9(a + 1)$$

But from the definition of $f(x)$, we have $f(1) = 81$. Hence it follows that $81 = 9(a + 1)$, which gives $a = 8$. Therefore,

$$f(x) = (4x - 1)^2(8x + 1)$$

You can expand this out to verify that it is true. Maybe you messed up your long division somewhere.