# how to factor this cubic polynomial

Tags: roots, factoring

Let $f(t)=36t^3-19t+5$ be a cubic polynomial.
How we can factor $f$ to its roots?

Mathematica says that $f(t)=(-1+2 t) (-1+3 t) (5+6 t)$. How?

Comment: All the roots are rational, so one may use the [Rational Root Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) followed by polynomial division to check each option.

Answer (score 3):

The [Rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) can be used here to find all roots of this polynomial

Comment: is there another way?

Comment: @MathMan  I can't think of any better way, maybe other answers will. Anyway, you can use this theorem without having to justify it - one you get the roots you can prove those are the roots by evaluating the polynomial at those points

Comment: How can you know all roots are rational, without looking at the mathematica result?

Comment: @MathMan Yes, guess the roots. Or use Cardano's formulas if you want to get messy.

Comment: If you check t=1/2  f(0.5)=0 so divide f(t) by t-0.5 to find others

Comment: @MathMan - This method finds all rational roots

Comment: You can't know all roots are rational except by testing all possible values. Cardano's formula won't work here as there are 3 real roots. You also can try a trigonometric method, but you'll have to use inverse trigonometric function.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ 6f(t) = (6t)^3\! -19(6t) + 30 = x^3\! - 19x + 30 =: g(x)\,$ for $\,x = 6t.$ By the [Rational Root Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) the only possible rational roots of $g$ are *integer* factors of $30.\,$

**Remark** $\ $ This is a generalization of the high-school "AC method" and it works generally to reduce finding rational roots to finding integer roots. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/816069/242) for much further discussion, including more general ring-theoretic viewpoints

Comment: The test does not require that the polynomial will be monic, why the extra step ?

Comment: @Belgi Because often reduction to the monic special case yields simplifications, both conceptually and computationally. Follow the link for more.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like using the rational root theorem is a good bet for this problem. If you feel it is tedious to use the rational root theorem to find all three roots, then use it to find just one root (or just plain guess and check until you find one root, like $t=\frac{1}{2}$) and then use polynomial division. Since $t=\frac{1}{2}$ is a root, you can divide your polynomial by $\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and will get $$36t^3-19t+5 =\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)(36t^2+18t-10)$$ From here you should be able to factor the quadratic portion $(36t^2+18t-10)$ by hand. The rest of the algebra should follow as: $$\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)(36t^2+18t-10) = \left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)2\cdot(18t^2+9t-5) \\ = \left(2\left[t-\frac{1}{2}\right]\right)(6t+5)(3t-1) \\ = (2t-1)(6t+5)(3t-1)$$ This technique will work for whichever of the three roots you begin with.

Comment: Better than solving a quadratic equation, you can use the hint in the previous answer: $g(x)$ also has rootequal to $2$, hence the root $\dfrac{2}{6}=\dfrac{1}{3}$ for $f(x)$. You'll find the last root using relations between coefficients and roots.

Answer (score 0):

And without using Rational root theorem:
$$36t^3-10t+5=36t^3-30t^2+30t^2-25t+6t+5$$
$$36t^3-10t+5=6t(6t^2-5t+1)+5(6t^2-5t+1)$$
$$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=(6t^2-5t+1)(6t+5)$$
$$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=(2t-1)(3t-1)(6t+5)$$