# How do I factorize a polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$ where $a \neq 1$

Tags: factoring

How do I factorize a polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$ where $a \neq 1$?

E.g. I know that $6x^2 + 5x + 1$ will factor to $(3x + 1)(2x + 1)$, but is there a recipe or an algorithm that will allow me to factorize this?

Comment: Find 2 numbers whose product is $ac$ and sum is $b$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The roots of a quadratic polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ are $x_1=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ and $x_2=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. Then the factorization is just $a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$.

In your example, $a=6,b=5,c=1$, so $x_1=\frac{-5+\sqrt{5^2-4\cdot 6\cdot1}}{2\cdot 6}=-\frac13$ and $x_2=\frac{-5-\sqrt{5^2-4\cdot 6\cdot1}}{2\cdot 6}=-\frac12$. The factorization is then $6(x+\frac13)(x+\frac12)$, or $(3x+1)(2x+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

If you are lucky enough to find "by guesswork" values $x_1$ and $x_2$ so that
$$x_1 + x_2 = -\frac{b}{a}$$
and
$$x_1 x_2 = \frac{c}{a}$$
Then you'll be able to factor $ax^2 + bx + c$ to $a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$.

Of course it will be easy to guess if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are integers.

Answer (score 2):

That **AC-method** reduces to factoring a polynomial that is $\,\rm\color{#c00}{monic}\,$ (lead coeff $\color{#c00}{=1})$ as follows

$$\begin{eqnarray} \rm\: a\:f(x)\:\! \,=\,\:\! a\:(a\:x^2 + b\:x + c)  &\,=\,&\!\!\rm\: \color{#c00}{X^2} + b\:X + \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!{\overbrace{ac,}^{\rm\qquad\ \ \ \ \ {\bf\large\ \  AC-method}}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \  X = a\:x \\
\end{eqnarray}$$ In your case $$ {\begin{eqnarray}
f \, &\,=\,& \ \ \,  6 x^2+\ 5\ x\,\ +\ \ 1\\
\Rightarrow\,\ 6f\, &\,=\,&\!\,\ (6x)^2\! +5(6x)+6\\
         &\,=\,& \ \ \   \color{#c00}{X^2}+\, 5\  X\,\ +\ 6,\,\ \ X\, =\, 6x\\
         &\,=\,&  \ \ (X+2)\ (X+\,3)\\
         &\,=\,& \  (6x+2)\,(6x+3)\\
\Rightarrow\ \  f\:=\: \color{#0a0}{6^{-1}}\,(6f)\,  &\,=\,&   \,  (3x+ 1)\ (2x+1)\\
\end{eqnarray}}$$

In the final step we cancel $\,\color{#0a0}6\,$  by cancelling $\,2\,$ from the first factor, and $\,3\,$ from the second.

If we denote our factoring algorithm by $\,\cal F,\,$ then the above transformation is simply

$$\cal F f\,  = a^{-1}\cal F\, a\,f\quad\,$$

Thus we've transformed by $ $ *conjugation* $\,\ \cal F = a^{-1} \cal F\, a\ \,$ the problem of factoring non-monic polynomials into the simpler problem of factoring monic polynomials. The same idea also works for higher degree polynomials, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1196213/242), which also gives links to closely-related ring-theoretic topics.

Comment: This is a very clear and simple algorithm. Exactly what I need. Also, the description is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: another possibility is to use the vieta's formulas
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas
but it's more a "guess and proof strategy"^^

Answer (score 1):

I actually learned this one neat trick in middle school. Take your polynomial 
$$6x^2+5x+1$$
Take out the leading coefficient, and multiply it into the constant term to get
$$x^2+5x+6$$
Now factor like usual 
$$(x+2)(x+3)$$
Divide both of those constant terms by the original leading coefficient, and reduce the fractions
$$\left(x+\frac{2}{6}\right)\left(x+\frac{3}{6}\right) = \left(x+\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
Now take the denominators and put them in front of the $x$ terms to get
$$(3x+1)(2x+1)$$
(this process essentially only works for polynomials with integer coefficients, and it assumes that there are no constant factors in the original polynomial)

Comment: This so-called AC method does not have any such restrictions - see my answer.

Comment: It does have these restrictions (or just the second one, at the very least) the way I stated it.

Comment: It works fine if there are constant factors, and it also works for far more general coefficient rings than the integers (the precise class of rings is described in my post linked in my answer).

Comment: If we do what I described with, say, $(3x+3)(2x+1) = 6x^2+9x+3$, we get $x^2+9x+18 \to (x+3)(x+6) \to (x+3/6)(x+6/6) \to (x+1/2)(x+1) \to (2x+1)(x+1)$, which is incorrect. I understand that this isn't what would happen with the algorithm in your post, but I'm just talking about mine.

Comment: Yes, to be precise, your final step does not work in general, but the general AC method has no such restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to factor polynomials for $a=1$, then simply writing
$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x^2+\frac bax+\frac ca )$$
makes the task immediate.